# JavaScript objects returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, npm

I'm sending a http request to an api endpoint which returns the following:

> {
>     "status": 200,
>     "headers": "{\"server\":\"nginx\",\"date\":\"Sat, 13 Jun 2015 22:29:35 GMT\",\"content-type\":\"application/json; charset=utf-8\",\"content-length\":\"223\",\"connection\":\"keep-alive\",\"status\":\"200 OK\",\"cache-control\":\"no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate\",\"pragma\":\"no-cache\",\"x-frame-options\":\"SAMEORIGIN\",\"vary\":\"Accept-Encoding\",\"x-ua-compatible\":\"IE=Edge,chrome=1\",\"set-cookie\":[\"_twitch_session_id=4654465464564645645646546; domain=.twitch.tv; path=/; expires=Sun, 14-Jun-2015 10:29:35 GMT; HttpOnly\"],\"x-request-id\":\"lostsOfStringsStuffHere\",\"x-runtime\":\"0.403684\",\"accept-ranges\":\"bytes\",\"x-varnish\":\"1124564703\",\"age\":\"0\",\"via\":\"1.1 varnish\",\"x-mh-cache\":\"rails-varnish-6db1a8; M\",\"front-end-https\":\"on\"}",
>     "body": "\"{\\"access_token\\":\\"lostsOfStringsStuffHere\\",\\"refresh_token\\":\\"lostsOfStringsStuffHere\\",\\"scope\\":[\\"user_read\\"]}\""
>   }

I then run following the de-serialize the body of the response:

```
var response = JSON.parse(response.body);
```

Which gives me this:

> {
>     "access_token":"lostsOfStringsStuffHere",
>     "refresh_token":"lostsOfStringsStuffHere",
>     "scope":["user_read"]
>   }

But when I try to access the individual items of the object, I get `undefined`.

Example:

```
console.log(response.access_token); // undefined
```

I'm new to working with json using JavaScript and have in the past used PHP's `json_decode()` function to process json for back-end projects.

I have done some searching but haven't come across an npm package that is perfect for dealing with json. Can anyone suggest one?

Comment: you really want to use http://jsonlint.com on that JSON

Comment: Could you show is the code that sends the request, maybe then we can find out why it gets returned as a string and not JSON.

Comment: @MarkEriksson I'm using [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Controllers) which offers a simple redirect method: `return res.redirect('url');`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an additional library.  JavaScript's built in `JSON` will do just fine.  Your issue is that the string that gets returned is escaped, so when you do `JSON.parse` on `response.body` the result is actually a *string*.

You could just parse it again: `JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.body)).access_token`

However I would look into why the body is being returned as a string.  Could be an issue with the API you are using or the http request library.  I think the extra string is unnecessary.